# How can I zip a folder in grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have a folder `"foo"`, but in my target folder `"target"` I want to send zip version of my `"foo"` folder such as `"foo.zip"`, I google and found many way for zipping files but not for folder, so how can we zip a whole folder in grunt ?

Comment: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compress/ ?

Comment: What happens if you just try zipping a directory as you would a file?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I try https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compress/ but it is compressing only file I want a zip folder of my foo, so that I can push that foo.zip in my target.

Comment: @TechDon Did you try `compress: { zip: { files: { './foo.zip': './foo/**' } } }`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The accepted answer was throwing an error in grunt-contrib-compress 0.5.0. Try this instead:

```
compress: {
    foo: {
        options: {
            archive: './foo.zip',
            mode: 'zip'
        },
        files: [
            { src: './foo/**' }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From above suggestion I am able to get my answer,We can use https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compress/ for zipping a folder.

```
compress: {
            zip:{ 
                  files: {
                            './foo.zip': './foo/**'
                         }
                }
          }
```

Comment: This no longer works. This creates ``foo.zip.gz`` and overwrites it with the gzipped content of every file nested in ``foo``.