# How can I zip a folder in grunt (2018)

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-compress

Referring to this post about grunt-contrib-compress: [How can I zip a folder in grunt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847432/how-can-i-zip-a-folder-in-grunt)

To this date when I try what they said was the fix, I receive this error:

> `Fatal error: path must be a string or Buffer.`

Can anyone tell me what this means?

Here is what I have:

```js
compress: {
  options: {
    archive: './build.zip',
    mode: 'zip'
  },
  files: [{
    src: './build/**',
    dest: 'ZipHere/'
  },]
}
```

I also request if everything can be explained to a full extent.

Comment: please provide complete grunt file. Also your package.json file

Comment: A lot of it is copyrighted so due to those reasons I'm afraid I cannot post that stuff, however what is required in those two files/ what should they looklike or have? @TroelsLenda

Comment: If you're very new to node, grunt and javascript it could be a ton of things im afraid.

Did you install the package `npm install grunt-contrib-compress --save-dev`

Comment: yes, its registered in my package.json in the devdependencies: "grunt-contrib-compress": "^1.4.3" @TroelsLenda

Comment: it looks like this in the end: Files: ./build/enhancedFeedLeft-win32-x64(this is what I'm trying to put into a zip) -> ZipHere/(that's where I'm trying to put it..? I'm assuming that's what that is?)
Fatal error: path must be a string or Buffer

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compress/) of grunt-contrib-compress youre missing main level in your json

```
compress: {
    main: {
        options: {
            archive: './build.zip',
            mode: 'zip'
        },
        files: [
            { src: ['./build/**'], dest: 'ZipHere/'}
        ]
    }
}
```

Furthermore src should be an array.

Does it change anything?

Comment: Ill have to check when I go in for work tomorrow, thank you for the help ill keep in touch :) @TroelsLenda

Comment: even when I use https://github.com/twolfson/grunt-zip to zip my build it spits out the same fatal error: Fatal error: path must be a string or Buffer